# Select an enum typedef by if-then-else conditional statement

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, enums, if-statement

I would like to use something like:

```
if (foo>0){
 typedef enum {  
   Form_FirstName = 0,
   Form_NamePrefix,
   Form_LastName,
   Form_Email,
   Form_Phone
 } Form; 
} else {
   typedef enum {
   Form_FirstName = 0,
   Form_LastName,
   Form_Phone
 } Form;
}
```

Can this be done? Where should I do this? In the .m or in the .h? I want to use this for an UITableView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Firstly, enumerations are compile type constructs.

Secondly, you have a scoping issue. Because you are defining the enumeration type within the scope of the `if` and the `else`. It will not have visibility outside of the `if..else..` statement.

You'll need to find a different way to differentiate your indexing based on a state.

**Updating based on OP's follow on question:**

OK, you need a map of some sort. For example you could do:

Define your enumeration.

```
enum {
   Form_FirstName = 0,
   Form_NamePrefix,
   Form_LastName,
   Form_Email,
   Form_Phone
};
```

Assuming your class has an `indexes` ivar with the usual `@property` and `@synthesize`, set up your indexes:

```
if (foo>0) {
    self.indexes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:Form_FirstName],[NSNumber numberWithInt:Form_NamePrefix],[NSNumber numberWithInt:Form_LastName],[NSNumber numberWithInt:Form_Email],[NSNumber numberWithInt:Form_Phone],nil];
}
else {
    self.indexes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:Form_FirstName],[NSNumber numberWithInt:Form_LastName],[NSNumber numberWithInt:Form_Email],[NSNumber numberWithInt:Form_Phone],nil];
}
```

Elsewhere, when you need to translate an enumerated field to an index:

```
NSInteger index = [self.indexes indexOfObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:<Form Enumeration Value>]];
```

Comment: Using a map of some sort. Either that provided by C++'s STL map (if you know C++), or roll your own with a `NSArray`. I have updated the answer with an example using `NSArray`.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I think I can do that. It is still easier then multiple tableviews :-)

Answer (score 1):

gschandler is correct, you can't do that.  Technically you could use a preprocessor command

```
#if something
    enum
#endif
```

But the real question is **why** you want to do the above.  What do you think it will do for you?  There's no harm in using just the first enum set.  Who cares if you don't **use** form_email?  It doesn't do any harm just sitting there.

Comment: The reason is that I want to use a switch in the - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath. Depending on the if-statement I want to use cells or skip cells. I have at least 3 different scenario's and more then 10 cells.

Comment: This seems OK as well. But I think the other answer is more conventional. Thank you anyway.